# Ошибка при обработки событий kivy

Tags: python, kivy

AttributeError: 'FloatLayout' object has no attribute 'test' появляется при обработки события нажатия на кнопку.
Код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Activity = '''
FloatLayout:
    
    Button:
        text: "Check product!"
        pos: 300, 250
        size_hint: .2, .2
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 228/255.0, 202/255.0, 31/255.0, 1
        on_press: root.test()

'''

class Program(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (184/255.0, 228/255.0, 107/255.0, 255/255.0)
        return Builder.load_string(Activity)
    def test(self):
        return("test is work!")
   
if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    Program().run()
```

Пробовал переустановить kivy к сожалению не помогло.

Comment: Убедительная просьба, выкладывайте полный код ошибки, так легче будет понять в какой троке ошибка

Comment: Если так посмотреть, то ошибка в строке `on_press: root.test()`, т.к. для `Button` `root` будет именно ваш `FloatLayout`, а он не имеет такого атрибута. Вам надо обратиться к самому классу `Program`. Значит, надо как-то обратиться к вашему файлу с `Program`, но как это сделать я не знаю(никогда с `kivy` не работал). Думаю, есть какой-то способ наложить на кнопку это событие извне. Если найду - сообщу

Comment: К сожалению, судя по всему, невозможно сделать событие так, как вы указываете. Это надо полностью переписывать программу и вставлять кнопку отдельно через класс `Button`, а затем на него навешивать `on_press`. Перепробовал все возможные варианты, ничего не вышло(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НАШЁЁЁЁЁЁЛ!!!!!!!!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Activity = f'''
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: "Check product!"
        pos: 300, 250
        size_hint: .2, .2
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 228/255.0, 202/255.0, 31/255.0, 1
        on_press: app.test()

'''

class Program(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (184/255.0, 228/255.0, 107/255.0, 255/255.0)
        return Builder.load_string(Activity)

    def test(self):
        print("test is work!")

Program().run()
```

Вот таким образом всё должно работать) Вы должны обращаться за методом к самому приложению, ведь он прописан именно в его классе.

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку, чтобы другие пользователи знали что ответ на вопрос был дан